Ubuntu installation over Bitlocker
Hello:  I am attempting to install the current version of Ubuntu on a Surface laptop that has windows with Bitlocker.  I am not trying to run both OS and I wish to completely erase the disk.  However, when I select that in the install sequence, I am prompted to turn off Bitlocker.  The instructions suggest that selecting Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu will do just that and not require any interaction with Bitlocker.  I am currently stuck, can anyone help?

This is for version 24.04.1 LTS.  The prompt is from the Ubuntu installation process.  After I chose to erase the contents of the drive, the installation program indicated that BitLocker needed to be turned off and offered an option to reboot to windows and turn it off.  Since I do not have the bitlocker encryption key, I was not able to move past this point.

I would start with a gparted live and then remove the partitions. afaik that should not trigger bitlocker.
